# CDI does not work in qualified jaxrs resource class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

Edit: I uploaded a [minimal example](http://www.filedropper.com/jaxrsqualifiertest). You can build with `mvn clean install` and after deployment, open the following urls:

http://localhost:8080/jaxrs-test/unqualified -> response: `Hello there: de.test.SomeBean@........`
http://localhost:8080/jaxrs-test/qualified -> response: `Hello there: null`

Tested on wildfly-23.0.0.Final with openjdk11.

---

Original quesion:

Consider the classes:

App.java - Jaxrs application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class App extends Application {
}
```

Q.java - qualifier annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Q {
}
```

X.java - some simple class:

```
public class X {
    public String getX(){
        return "some x";
    }
}
```

Foo.java - jaxrs resource:

```
@Path("/foo")
@Q
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    private X test;

    @Path("bar")
    @GET
    public String getBar() {
        return test.getX();
    } 
}
```

The pom contains the following dependencies (and nothing else relevant):

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

After building this application and deploying it to a wildfly server, a reques to

```
http://localhost:8080/app/api/foo/bar
```

leads to a null pointer exception, because `test` in the Foo resource is null.
The request and injection of `X` works perfectly when removing the qualifier annotation.

Why is that? I could not find anything in the documentation suggesting that.
Is there any way to get CDI working in a qualified jaxrs-resource class?

With qualified I mean any qualifier besides `@Named`, since the latter does not prevent the class to get the qualifier `@Default`.

Comment: Could you show the stacktrace. There must be something wrong in your interpretation of the error.

Comment: I'm being just curious, but why do you need a JAX-RS endpoint with a `@Qualifier` annotation ??

Comment: @aschoerk: There is no stacktrace except of the plain default null pointer exception.
See my edit, I uploaded a minimal example - you can test it yourself.

Comment: @CarlitosWay: I needed some hack to "circumvent" some existing endpoint. I solved the problem with decorators, eventually, but I'm still curious what I am doing wrong here.